# Using MVC3, how do I set a TempData value when the user clicks on an HTML.ActionLink control?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a foreach loop that generates a table row for each item in an array of Business objects in the BusinessList view.

Here's my Business object:

```
    public class Business
    {
        public long BusinessID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

and here's the Razor foreach loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="editor">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editor">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditBusiness")
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

What I want to do is capture the BusinessID associated with the row in which the user clicks on the "Edit" button. The BusinessID value will need to be available to the EditBusiness view. I'd rather not use the querystring. Is there some way to set a ViewData, TempData, or ViewBag value when the user clicks the "Edit" link?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to pass the value via the url?

Comment: Yes. The businessID is the unique identifier in my Business database table. It's not something the user should ever see. At the very least, consuming an invalid ID can create a bad user experience. Worst case scenario, the user gets either a business that doesn't belong to them or they end up editing the wrong one.

Yes, I have other security measures in place to make sure the user doesn't get a business they are not authorized to view, but that's outside the scope of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use pass the value as a querystring you could post the value by changing the edit link to a form with a hidden field for the ID and a submit button (styled like your edit link)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditBusiness")) {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
}
```

Or you could post via ajax.

Comment: When I submit the form, what is it returning? A model, a string, a long or something else entirely? How can I see what it's returning?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set the ViewData, TempData or ViewBag values on the client side (browser) because they are properties of a ASP.NET MVC view object on the server side.
For what you need, you can use the `ActionLink` method like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditBusiness", new { Model.BusinessID })
```

This way, you will call the action `http://<your_host>/Edit/EditBusiness/<BusinessId>`

Comment: Won't that put the ID in the querystring?

Comment: Yes, but the RESTful way pressupposes that the resource you want to edit is already created. So the way to access that resource is by telling on the URL link.

Comment: I agree, but he did state that he didn't want to do that.

Comment: @Richard: yes, you're absolutely right. But in order to not change the code he has, there isn't another way that I know...

Answer (score 1):

Change your "EditBusiness" action method to accept BusinessID parameter.

```
public ActionResult EditBusiness(string BusinessID )
```

and change your actionlink to this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditBusiness", new { BusinessID = Model.BusinessID })
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create an Action like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
    //....

  return View();
}
```

---

Then, on the View (.cshtml file) add the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Business", new { id = Model.BusinessID })
```

Make sure method parameter name (Edit(**int id**)) is the same as "**id** = Model.BusinessID", which is "id".